# How to make apache2 serve HTTPS on port 443 and non-default ports?

Tags: apache2, ssl, https

I would like my `apache2` instance to serve HTTPS (a simple page or really just anything) on default port 443 just be available, e.g. for `letsencrypt` certificate installation client and to serve multiple services (wikis, issue trackers, etc.) on other ports (e.g. `dokuwiki` on port 446).

Serving those non-default ports worked fine for multiple services before enabling HTTPS on port 443 (see below) with site configurations like

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:446 https

Alias /dokuwiki/ "/var/www/html/dokuwiki/"

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html

<Directory "/var/www/html/dokuwiki">
    Options None
    AllowOverride Limit

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost [hostname]:446 >
    ErrorLog /var/log/dokuwiki/dokuwiki.log
    SSLEngine On
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/dokuwiki"
    ServerName [hostname]
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/[hostname]/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/[hostname]/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

After enabling `Listen 443` in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, turning `SSLEngine` `on` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf` and specifying the SSL certificate and key in `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile`, `dokuwiki` is served with HTTPS on port 443 and 446 no longer serves HTTPS, but `apache2` uses the port according to `netstat -tupln`.

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` is

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin admin@[hostname]

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/[hostname]/fullchain.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/[hostname]/privkey.pem

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I guess `dokuwiki` is served on port 443 because it matches with the directory structure. I have to figure out how to turn that off, but that's a separate problem. I don't get why 446 is no longer served (`firefox` 47.0 displays `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` and says that the site simply doesn't serve HTTPS and the `dokuwiki` site log contains `[Thu Jul 21 14:42:48.803900 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 13028] AH01914: Configuring server richtercloud.de:443 for SSL protocol` which doesn't make any sense). Is this a bug?

I found https://serverfault.com/questions/528210/bind-apache-ssl-port-with-different-port-with-same-openssl-port-443, but the solution there is my problem.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works fine now with the described settings. The behaviour might be because of `firefox` cache loading nonsense.